# lexer, parser , trying to make an expression calculator

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, calculator, yacc, ply

As the title says am trying to make an expression calculator using Ply , I still didnt finish the complete code just a part of it , but until now . I get this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "EX3.py", line 69, in
>   module 
>      parser = yacc.yacc()    File "/Users/mostafa.osama2/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ply/yacc.py",
>   line 3317, in yacc
>      raise YaccError('Unable to build parser')
>  ply.yacc.YaccError: Unable to build parser

here is my code :

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc
import sys

tokens = ['INT','FLOAT' , 'NAME' , 'PLUS' , 'MINUS' , 'DIVIDE' , 'MULTIPLY' ,
'EQUALS']

#list of tokens , for grammar checking

t_PLUS = r'\+'
t_MINUS = r'\-'
t_MULTIPLY = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE = r'\/'
t_EQUALS = r'\='

t_ignore = r' ' # used for ignoring spaces between numbers and operators

#has to match name of token, 

def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'\d+.\d+' # 1.2 is a float , 1.any number is a float
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

def t_INT(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t # t is our token object


def t_NAME(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*' #star means 0 or more, first char is a-zA-z , second character is a-zA-z0-9
    t.type = 'NAME'
    return t

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal characters!")
    t.lexer.skip(1) # skips 1 token onwards

lexer = lex.lex()

def p_calc(p): # p is  a  tuple
    '''
    calc : expression
        | empty
    '''
    print(p[1])

def p_expression(p):
    '''
    expression : expression PLUS expression
                | expression DIVIDE expression
                | expression PLUS expression
                | expression MINUS expression
    '''
    p[0] = (p[2] , p[1] , p[3])
def p_expression(p):
    '''
    expression : INT
                | FLOAT
    '''
    p[0] = p[1]
def p_empty(p):
    '''
    empty:
    '''
    p[0] = None

parser = yacc.yacc()
while True:
    try:
        s = input('')
    except EOFError: # when u press contorl D on keyboard
        break
        parser.parse(s)
```

Comment: You should quote  all of the error messages, which would be much more informative. (Also, you should *read* the entire sequence of error messages, which might have helped you solve the problem yourself.)

Comment: I dont understand, there is only 1 error message and its in the question

Comment: I ran python3 on that file and it gave me two PLY error messages before it produced the traceback. Look more carefully. (`ERROR: c.py:65: Syntax error in rule 'empty:'` and `WARNING: c.py:57: Function p_expression redefined. Previously defined on line 49`)

Answer (score 3):

Ply insists that parsing rules have whitespace between the name of the non-terminal and the colon. So `empty:` is not valid; you must write `empty :`

Also, as reported by Ply, you define two functions named `p_expression`. Ply requires that all parsing functions have different names (otherwise it has no way to call them), but it doesn't care what the names are, as long as they start with `p_`. So change one of the names.

Finally, you have two rules for addition, and no rule for multiplication. Ply will complain about the duplicate addition rule (after you fix the other problems). It will also complain that you are missing a `p_error` function.